# Python: Copy parent attribute, giving it the same name

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

Is it possible to create a new attribute in child class, which will have the same name and values (a copy of the main attribute) as the parent attribute?
This attribute will be then inherited by all sub-child classes.

My problem is that I am allowed only to change class Lanc (not allowed to make corrections on other classes), and only class superLanc should inherit that attribute. Looking at class superLanc, `return self.brand` should return that new attribute of child class Lanc.

```
class Machine(object):     
    def __init__(self, brand):         
        self.brand = brand     
    def start(self, attr):         
        return self.brand + attr     
    def __str__(self):         
        return self.brand  

class Mitsh(Machine):     
    def mEng(self, attr):         
        return Machine.start(self, attr)  

class Lanc(Mitsh):
    def start(self, attr):
        return self.brand + Mitsh.mEng(self, attr)

class superLanc(Lanc):
    def start(self, attr): 
        return self.brand + Mitsh.mEng(self, attr)
    def mEng(self, attr):
        return Mitsh.mEng(self, attr)
```

Comment: You can certainly override `Lanc.__init__` and set `self.brand` to whatever you want.  I don't understand from your example what you really want to achieve.  Can you show how you want to *use* those classes?

Comment: This is an exercise, it has no real purpose.
I just want that a new self.brand is defined in class Lanc, which will have same values as parent self.brand, plus some additional values.
When it is called through superLanc, it will return those new values, while calls to Mitsh.mEng(self, attr) will still provide the self.brand values of Machine (parent).

Comment: I don't think you can achieve that.  Any code in any superclass of a given instance that uses `self` will be referring to the same object, so `self.brand` will have the same result no matter which class is accessing it.  (Incidentally, that seems quite different from what your question asks.  Your question doesn't say anything about wanting `self.brand` to give different results depending on which class is calling it.)

Comment: Yes, it should give different results depending on which class is calling it, but I am only allowed to change Lanc.

Comment: Then, like I said, that's not possible.  `self` is not a class, it's an instance, and it's the same instance no matter which of the superclasses is using it.  You can't have `self.brand` evaluate to one thing in `Mitsh` and a different thing i `superLanc`.  (You could maybe do it with name-mangled double-underscore attributes, but that would require modifying the superclasses, which you say you can't do.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question. A class is a definition of what a class is (attributes) and how it behaves (methods). A child class inherits the definition of a parent class and "improves" it.

But values of the attributes are not inherited, they are just states of the classes called instances.

For me, you are talking as a child class can inherit the values of the parent class and that's no true (besides of class attributes).

So, in my opinion, if you want (really I don't what you want) that an instance of a child class "knows" about an instance of the parent class probably you should pass a reference to the "parent" instance to "child" instance.

You can also use some kind of composition in the child class (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) or you can pass this reference to any method which requires it.

Sorry. I'm not sure that I can help you.

Comment: I am allowed to change only class Lanc, so that both Lanc.start and superLanc.start print a modified self.brand attribute. eg "Hello: " + self.brand